# Parse save ParseGeoPoint by objectId fails with "com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException:"

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, objectid

Following [instructions here](https://parse.com/questions/updating-a-field-without-retrieving-the-object-first) to save data to an object by `objectId` thru android app and getting errmsg `com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException:` (without anything following semicolon). I have confirmed objectId is as shown in parse dashboard. Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing incorrectly? Thanks

```
final String parseRequest = "Request";
final String parseRequestDriverLocation = "driverLocation";

private void saveDriverLocation(String objectId, Location driverLocation) {
  Log.i("saveDriverLocation", "objectId=" + objectId + ", driverLocation=" + driverLocation.toString());

  ParseGeoPoint locationDriverParse = new ParseGeoPoint(driverLocation.getLatitude(), driverLocation.getLongitude());
  ParseObject acceptedRequest = ParseObject.createWithoutData(parseRequest, objectId);

  Log.i("saveDriverLocation", "acceptedRequest=" + acceptedRequest.toString() + "\nlocationDriverParse=" + locationDriverParse.toString());

  acceptedRequest.put(parseRequestDriverLocation, locationDriverParse);
  acceptedRequest.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
      if (e == null) {
        Log.i("saveDriverLocation", "driver location saved successfully");
      } else {
        Log.i("saveDriverLocation", "saving driver location failed... " + e.toString());
      }
    }
  });
}
```

The logcat:

```
I/saveDriverLocation: objectId=Ddm73yXhPC, driverLocation=Location[gps 41.677770,-80.385998 acc=20 et=+1d7h59m59s883ms alt=18.0 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=40]}]
I/saveDriverLocation: acceptedRequest=com.parse.ParseObject@ddeb183
locationDriverParse=ParseGeoPoint[41.677770,-80.385998]
I/saveDriverLocation: saving driver location failed... com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently a Parse class can only have one ParseGeoPoint column! Here is [reference](https://www.parse.com/questions/store-more-than-one-parse-geopoint).